# Is there a non trivial way to visit every red node in a red black tree?

Tags: data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree, red-black-tree

The obvious solution to counting the number of red nodes in a red-black tree is to do a simple recursion that visits every node and counts the node if it is indeed red. But is there any property of red-black tress you can exploit to this faster than O(n) time? I cannot figure out what property could make this operation quicker.

Answer (score 2):

There is no property of a generic red-black tree that would allow you to count red nodes in other than O(n) time. If the number of red nodes is of extreme importance for some reason you could make the count a property of the tree itself and keep track of manipulations during the insert/remove rebalance.

Even the theoretical possibility of skipping the node color check on children of red nodes (which could be done since those children have to be black in order for the tree to be valid) isn't reasonable since it is likely the checks in that case would be no simpler than directly checking node colors. And those black children still have to be visited in order for the examination to continue down the tree.